# WMI Query to get enabled user accounts. What is wrong with my WHERE clause?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I am trying to get a list of non-disabled user accounts on the local computer with SID values for each user.  I could not make this work with the DirectoryEntry class because the returned users all had NULL in the ObjectSecurity field.  So I tried to use ManagementObjectSearcher

```
SelectQuery sQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount"); );
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery);
```

The returned users have the information I need but this query gives me disabled accounts.  I'd like to add a WHERE clause to account for that but I can't get it right.

I've tried

```
new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount WHERE NOT Disabled");
new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled='False'");
new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=False");
```

All of these cause an exception.  Can someone tell me how to word this?

Comment: are you looking to query the SID value ?

Comment: You should look at the documentation for [`SelectQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.selectquery); you're not using it correctly. But even better, IMO, you could simplify it by just using the constructor for `ManagementObjectSearcher` that takes a query string: `new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=False")`

Comment: That was it.  Guess if I was bothering with a WHERE clause I should have bothered with the "SELECT" part!

Comment: does the answer below help @Joe ?

Comment: It does.  I saw herohtar's answer first (which was also correct) and marked that the answer.  Apologies if I got the order of answers wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using [`SearchQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.selectquery) correctly; to specify a condition, you have to either give a *full* query string, or use the [`SearchQuery(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.selectquery.-ctor#System_Management_SelectQuery__ctor_System_String_System_String_) constructor that takes the query separately:

```
var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=False");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
```

## OR

```
var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "Disabled=False");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
```

However, you can simplify your code by using the [`ManagementObjectSearcher(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.-ctor) constructor that takes a query string directly:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=False");
```

Answer (score 0):

- `ManagementObjectSearcher` retrieves a collection of management objects based on a specified query in our case `SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount`
- `userSearcher.Get()` : Invokes the specified WMI query and returns the resulting collection.

Add `System.Management` in reference

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    ManagementObjectSearcher usersSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount");
    ManagementObjectCollection users = usersSearcher.Get();

    var localUsers = users.Cast<ManagementObject>().Where(
        u => (bool)u["Disabled"] == false);

    foreach (ManagementObject user in localUsers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account Type: " + user["AccountType"].ToString());               
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name: " + user["FullName"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("SID: " + user["SID"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("SID Type: " + user["SIDType"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Status: " + user["Status"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Disabled: " + user["Disabled"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + user["Domain"].ToString());
    }
 }
```

OR

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    ManagementObjectSearcher usersSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE Disabled=False");
    ManagementObjectCollection users = usersSearcher.Get();


    foreach (ManagementObject user in users)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Account Type: " + user["AccountType"].ToString());               
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name: " + user["FullName"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("SID: " + user["SID"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("SID Type: " + user["SIDType"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Status: " + user["Status"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Disabled: " + user["Disabled"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Domain: " + user["Domain"].ToString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: There is no reason to use LINQ here when you can write the condition directly in the query string.

Comment: I updated both the ways with and without LINQ, thanks